# Unable to read XML File stored in GCS Bucket

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have tried to follow this documentation in the most precise way I could:

https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/xml/XmlIO.html

Please find below my codes :

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    DataflowPipelineOptions options=PipelineOptionsFactory.as(DataflowPipelineOptions.class);
     options.setTempLocation("gs://balajee_test/stagging");
     options.setProject("test-1-130106");

     Pipeline p=Pipeline.create(options);

     PCollection<XMLFormatter> record= p.apply(XmlIO.<XMLFormatter>read()
             .from("gs://balajee_test/sample_3.xml")
             .withRootElement("book")
             .withRecordElement("author")
             .withRecordElement("title")
             .withRecordElement("genre")
             .withRecordElement("price")
             .withRecordElement("description")
             .withRecordClass(XMLFormatter.class)
             );

     record.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<XMLFormatter,String>(){
                @ProcessElement

                public void processElement(ProcessContext c)
                {
                    System.out.println(c.element().getAuthor());    
                }
             }));

     p.run(); 
}
```

I'm getting '**null**' value for every XML component. Could you please review my code and suggest me the corrective course of action required?

[image: Test File]

```
package com.bitwise.cloud;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"author", "title","genre","price","description"})
public class XMLFormatter {
private String author;
private String title;
private String genre;
private String price;
private String description;

public XMLFormatter() { }

public XMLFormatter(String author, String title,String genre,String price,String description) {
this.author = author;
this.title = title;
this.genre = genre;
this.price = price;
this.description = description;
}

@XmlElement
public void setAuthor(String author) {
this.author = author;
}

public String getAuthor() {
return author;
}

@XmlElement
public void setTitle(String title) {
this.title = title;
}

public String getTitle() {
return title;
}

@XmlElement
public void setGenre(String genre) {
this.genre = genre;
}

public String getGenre() {
return genre;
}

@XmlElement
public void setPrice(String price) {
this.price = price;
}

public String getPrice() {
return price;
}


@XmlElement
public void setDescription(String description) {
this.description = description;
}

public String getDescription() {
return description;
}
}
```

Comment: What runner are you using? The DirectRunner? Dataflow Runner? Something else? Do you have a job ID for the failing pipeline?

Comment: Tried using DirectRunner as well as DataflowRunner. I do have a job ID for the failing Pipeline (2017-08-30_02_55_24-4448720439481076797). Would you mind sharing a working code sample for reading an XML file?

Comment: @BenChambers Could you please review my code?Still  I haven't been able to resolve this issue. It would be quite helpful if you share any working snippet for the same.

Comment: Can you provide your test file?

Comment: Have you tried running a DirectPipeline from a txt file instead of a GCS file? That would allow you to know that the issue is reading GCS or with the XML formatter. Or you could try reading from a GCS file and writing the output by line to verify that the GCS file is able to be read.

Comment: @LaraSchmidt Added the snap of my test file as well as code of 'XMLFormatter' class. Please check the codes and let me know the piece I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Everything looks okay. Does the pipeline run if you read from a text file using direct runner?

Comment: Hi Lara !!! The Pipeline runs and reads the file successfully if provided as a text file. It seems that 'XmlIo' is unable to map the XML elements to their corresponding setters and so getters of 'XMLFormatter' class. Getting 'null' values at output is literally surprising to me. Any thoughts?

Comment: Any update? @LaraSchmidt

Comment: Great support :D would be happy to see a working snippet, too! Since Apache is handling the library, documentation and solution-searching became quite annoying :-(

Comment: @BalajeeVenkatesh this issue has been triaged by Lara internally and is now being investigated by additional engineers. There is no ETA for the fix but they should reply here with additional information when it becomes available. Since this has been escalated internally you may wish to move this to the [Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) as that is the correct place to report Google-end issues.

Comment: I don't believe XMLIO supports record elements with different element names (author, title, genre, etc). You have to provide a single root element and a record element and your XML document has to contain records that have the same record element. See the example given in the doc string: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/xml/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/xml/XmlIO.java#L59

Comment: @BalajeeVenkatesh any updates guys where you able to solve it. has this issue been resolved yet.

Comment: @chamikara any updates guys where you able to solve it. has this issue been resolved yet.

Comment: @LaraSchmidt has this issue been reolved Lara. If you provide me some updates it would be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

XmlIO.Read PTransform doesn't support providing multiple record elements (author, title, genre, etc). You have to provide a single root element and a record element and your XML document has to contain records that have the same record element. See the example given in the following location.

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/xml/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/xml/XmlIO.java#L59